# jQuery Reload live Page and Stop?

Tags: refresh, reload, jquery

I am checking to see if a url contains the word "rewrite", if it does I am adding a cookie.  However, I want to reload the page after the cookie is added, then stop reloading the page.  Currently it keeps reloading the page because it sees the url and it contains the word "rewrite".  Is there like a `Do Once` in jQuery or a `Stop()` method?  Perhpas I have to use `.live()?`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($.cookie('logged_in') == null) {
        Do Nothing
        } else {
        Do Something
    }
});

$(document).ready(function () {                     
    if (/rewrite/.test(self.location.href)) {
        $.cookie("logged_in", 1, { expires : 1 });
        location.reload(); stop();
    }
});
```

**SOLVED**

```
if (/rewrite/.test(self.location.href)) {
    if ($.cookie('logged_in') == null) {
        $.cookie("logged_in", 1, { expires : 1 });
        location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for rewrite in the URL AND the cookie, if both then you know you've already done the reload?

Comment: Yeah that would do it.  Of course its something simple...rearrange the code, thank you.

Comment: Could have also done if (/rewrite/.test(self.location.href) && $.cookie('logged_in') == null)